# Algorithm for calculating variable column widths for set table width

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to figure out an algorithm that will calculate the optimized size of the column widths given the following:

- the width of the table is fixed to the size of the page
- the data inside the columns will be variable thus the width of the columns are variable
- the width must be optimized to know when to wrap a column and when not to

So given the following data:

```
'From' => '03/06/2014',
'To' => '03/06/2014',
'First Name' => 'John Doe',
'Status' => 'approved',
'Type' => 'PTO',
'Amount' => '8 Hours',
'Notes' => 'Oops! Who knew I would need one more day. This should be all I need over the next week to support my trip.'
```

How can I calculate the optimal column widths so that the 'notes' column does not squeeze the other widths down to a less than acceptable width?

[image: Sample of Problem]

**UPDATE:** I currently know the width of the page & the width of the font so I can calculate the max width requirements for each column. It should fill the available space on the page. However, I would prefer the columns not wrap unless necessary. Like this:

[image]

Comment: You could ask each cell their preferred min/max widhts.

Comment: Just give every column only the minimum width it needs. If there is  a solution, this is possible

Comment: Do you have any constraints like date columns must not wrap? And are you allowed to have a minimum nbr of chars that should be show, before wrapping?

Comment: Currently there are no constraints. However, we should be able to statistically determine if a cell CAN wrap or SHOULD wrap. For example, the date fields will all be 10 characters with no spaces. We should be able to determine that this is a very fixed width and display it accordingly.

Comment: ok. thanks. I am supposing yo will want to print more than one row of data per page. ie.. should the algo consider multiple records?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Multiple rows with multiple records. I also may have other reports that have a different number of columns as well. The only thing that is set is the width of the page.

Answer (score 7):

An easy solution is to assign attributes to your colums; for example your `Notes` columns could be `flexible`. Then you could calculate the maximum width of each column over all rows, set that width for all non-flexible columns and then distribute the remaining space evenly (or possibly weighted by their max width) to the flexible columns.

But you could also try to find out the attributes with some simple conditions:

- a column can be word-wrapped if any of its entries has spaces in it. In your example, the dates and possibly the status and type entries cannot be wrapped. The name shouldn't be wrapped under normal circumstances but could be wrapped, if the name is long or if more than one name is given. The notes column should be wrapped.
- a column should be flexible if its maximum width exceeds, say, the width a cell would have if all sizes were evenly distributed.

Then go about as described above: Calculate all non-flexible columns width. Check if there is enough space; if not, make the wrappable columns flexible, too. Then calculate the width of the flexible cells, weighted by their maximum widths.

A possible pseudocode algorithm is below. It makes liberal use of various heuristics, so you should probably take it with a grain of salt. You can adjust these conditions according to your use case, but it will be difficult to cater for all possible cases.

```
function layout(table[], width, gutter, col[])

    var maxw[col.length]        # max. text width over all rows
    var maxl[col.length]        # max. width of longest word
    var flex[col.length]        # is column flexible?
    var wrap[col.length]        # can column be wrapped?
    var colw[col.length]        # final width of columns

    foreach row in table:
        for i = 0 to col.length:
            cell = row[i]
            maxw[i] = max(maxw[i], textwidth(cell))
            if cell.find(" "):
                maxl[i] = max(maxl[i], wordwidth(cell))

    var left = width - (col.length - 1) * gutter
    var avg = left / col.length
    var nflex = 0

    # determine whether columns should be flexible and assign
    # width of non-flexible cells

    for i = 0 to col.length:
        flex[i] = (maxw[i] > 2 * avg)       # ???
        if flex[i]:
            nflex++
        else:
            colw[i] = maxw[i]
            left -= colw[i]

    # if there is not enough space, make columns that could
    # be word-wrapped flexible, too

    if left < nflex * avg:
        for i = 0 to col.length:
            if !flex[i] and wrap[i]:
                left += width[i]
                colw[i] = 0
                flex[i] = true
                nflex += 1

    # Calculate weights for flexible columns. The max width
    # is capped at the page width to treat columns that have to 
    # be wrapped more or less equal

    var tot = 0
    for i = 0 to col.length:
        if flex[i]:
            maxw[i] = min(maxw[i], width)      # ???
            tot += maxw[i]

    # Now assign the actual width for flexible columns. Make
    # sure that it is at least as long as the longest word length

    for i = 0 to col.length:
        if flex[i]:
            colw[i] = left * maxw[i] / tot
            colw[i] = max(colw[i], maxl[i])
            left -= colw[i]

    return colw
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! +1 This is similar to what I have already built. I used a Standard Deviation calculation to determine wrap flexibility. It takes away the need to manually designate which columns are flexible so it will handle custom reporting. I also do an average calculation to know how must space to assign to each column.  It works for the most part. But it's not quite where I need it to be.

Comment: Judging from your example, your columns are just a bit too narrow, which leads to all columns being wrapped, even the ones without break points. (Oddly, "8 hours" does now wrap.) So you might want to widen the small narrow columns and bring them to their minumum width by taking space away away from the notes column. (Or perhaps by taking space away evenly from all columns that are more than wide enough.)

Comment: You are correct. However, these column widths are being calculated dynamically. We do not have the widths assigned. This is the purpose of the question. To polish the algorithm to see if we can get closer to the correct widths statistically.

Comment: Yes, but that's _also_ the purpose of my proposed pseudocode. (You make it sound as if I hadn't understood the question. I think I have.) I actually have implemented the algorithm in Python (with output to a terminal with fixed-width characters, where the text width is just the string length) and then retrofitted that into pseudocode, because I didn't know what language you were using. The results looked okay, but I can compare that only to the screenshot of your results, of course.

Comment: For anyone actually implementing this in an editor or so-forth, an easy improvement is to weight the priority (using whatever heuristics you want) of both the wrappable and flexible columns. Priority on the flexible columns is used for space allocation. Priority on the wrappable columns is used to iterativatively turn them into flexible columns only as needed. Basically, the "if there is not enough space" part of M Oehm's algorithm on, but applied iteratively. I've had good results using this modification to the method.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C publishes algorithms for stuff like this in it's [CSS 3 Tables Algorithms](https://drafts.csswg.org/css3-tables-algorithms/Overview.src.htm).

A simpler algorithm that I have used successfully and is quite trivial to implement can be found in the [HTML4.1 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.5.2):

> The minimum and maximum cell widths are then used to determine the
>   corresponding minimum and maximum widths for the columns. These in
>   turn, are used to find the minimum and maximum width for the table.
>   Note that cells can contain nested tables, but this doesn't complicate
>   the code significantly. The next step is to assign column widths
>   according to the available space (i.e., the space between the current
>   left and right margins).
>
> For cells that span multiple columns, a simple approach consists of
>   apportioning the min/max widths evenly to each of the constituent
>   columns. A slightly more complex approach is to use the min/max widths
>   of unspanned cells to weight how spanned widths are apportioned.
>   Experiments suggest that a blend of the two approaches gives good
>   results for a wide range of tables.
>
> The table borders and intercell margins need to be included in
>   assigning column widths. There are three cases:
>
> - The minimum table width is equal to or wider than the available space. In this case, assign the minimum widths and allow the user to scroll horizontally. For conversion to braille, it will be necessary to replace the cells by references to notes containing their full content. By convention these appear before the table.
> - The maximum table width fits within the available space. In this case, set the columns to their maximum widths.
> - The maximum width of the table is greater than the available space, but the minimum table width is smaller. In this case, find the difference between the available space and the minimum table width, lets call it W. Lets also call D the difference between maximum and minimum width of the table.
>     For each column, let d be the difference between maximum and minimum width of that column. Now set the column's width to the minimum width plus d times W over D. This makes columns with large differences between minimum and maximum widths wider than columns with smaller differences.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem similar to this using ITextPDF with a 14 column table. The data was variable, where some columns could wrap and others couldn't.

My solution was to find the largest word in each column by using split(" "). This reduces the odds of a word, date or number getting cut in half. Here is the code. Sorry I don't have time to edit this to a more general format, hopefully it will help someone anyways.

```
//This array will store the largest word found in each of the 14 columns
int[] maxStringLengthPerColumn = new int[14];
for(int i = 0; i < maxStringLengthPerColumn.length; i++)
    maxStringLengthPerColumn[i]=0;

//for each row in table...

ArrayList<PdfPRow> rows = table.getRows();
for(int a = 0; a < rows.size(); a++){


    //for each cell in row
    PdfPCell[] cellsInRow = rows.get(a).getCells();
    for(int b = 0; b < cellsInRow.length; b++){

        //Split cell contents at " " and find longest word in each cell
        String[] splitCell = cellsInRow[b].getPhrase().getContent().split(" ");


        //find the longest string left after split
        int largestStringSize = 0;
        for(int c = 0; c < splitCell.length; c++){
            if(splitCell[c].length()>largestStringSize){
                largestStringSize=splitCell[c].length();
            }
        }

        if(largestStringSize>maxStringLengthPerColumn[b]){
            //I found that adding 4 to the value worked, change this number to fine tune.
            maxStringLengthPerColumn[b] = largestStringSize + 4;
        }
    }
}

/*The pdf library can set width with just an array, you may need to 
convert these values to something else depending on the application. For 
example if you have a width of 800 pixels, the width of col1 would be 
maxStringLengthPerColumn[0] / (sum of maxString0 - 13) * 800*/

table.setWidths(maxStringLengthPerColumn);
```