# FInd optimal column widths given total width and cell areas

Tags: algorithm

Problem description: Given a rectangular array of data we want to display them in a table of given width W and minimal height H. Some data items take more space than others. I can live with the simplifying assumption that the space requirement of the item can be expressed in terms of an area a<sub>ij</sub>.

More formally, find positive w<sub>1</sub>+...+w<sub>m</sub>=W minimizing H=h<sub>1</sub>+...+h<sub>n</sub> subject to a<sub>ij</sub> <= h<sub>i</sub>w<sub>j</sub>

This feels like a standard problem to me but I wasn't able to [find much on it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22206825/15752941).

My question is:

Is this indeed a standard problem? I.e. does it have a name? Is it a hard problem? Are there textbook algorithms for solving it?

Comment: Seems like a kind of 2D bin packing problem

Comment: I believe this is an optimization problem that's solved by [Linear Prorgramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)

Comment: Thanks @ArnabDe but is it really linear? There are products of unknowns.

Comment: Could you make a quick drawing of what you want to achieve ? I have a hard time imagining the final result.